# Run a django script and return the result to React

Tags: reactjs, django, post, request

I'm trying to send lat and lon from a marker from react to django and run a script that will calculate distances between this point with thge ones on my database, how can I achieve this? I'm new to this and I can't find a good tutorial.

Input:

```
Marker:  -33.442249608 -70.628815668
```

This is the output of my script on django:

```
[{'Lat': -36.828233049999994, 'Lon': -73.04807725260355}, {'Lat': -39.0989346, 'Lon': -72.6724288}, {'Lat': -34.727836, 'Lon': -71.6440839}]
```

Comment: You can leverage django APIs, check documentation https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: Good Django+React tutorial https://saasitive.com/django-react/boilerplate/